# Unresolved dependencies & Missing global variable name when trying to import @mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder

Tags: node-modules, mapbox-gl-js, svelte, rollup

I'm beginning with Svelte and I would like to (more or less) reproduce Mapbox store locator tutorial with Svelte & rollup. (Starting from svelte REPL starter kit).

Everything's fine for loading a map and some markers, but as soon as I try to import this package https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder, nothing works anymore and I'm not familiar enough with Svelte to figure out how to setup rollup and fix it.

```
<script>
    import { onMount, setContext } from 'svelte'
    import mapbox from 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';
    import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder'; // <<--- Problem here

    mapbox.accessToken = 'xxx';

    let map;
    let geocoder;
    
    onMount(() => {
        map = new mapbox.Map({,,,});
        geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({,,,});
    });
</script>
```

terminal :

```
bundles src/main.js → public/build/bundle.js...
(!) Missing shims for Node.js built-ins
Creating a browser bundle that depends on 'events'. You might need to include https://github.com/ionic-team/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
events (imported by node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/lib/index.js, events?commonjs-external)
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
events (guessing 'events$1')
created public/build/bundle.js in 2s
```

browser console :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: events$1 is not defined
    at main.js:5
```

Then, I tried to add to my rollup config resolve and polyfills plugins, but have other errors.

rollup.config.js

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve(),
        nodePolyfills(),
        svelte({
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file - better for performance
            css: css => {
                css.write('bundle.css');
            },
            preprocess: preprocess()
        }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),

        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};

function serve() {
    let started = false;

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (!started) {
                started = true;

                require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                    stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                    shell: true
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Gives me this

```
bundles src/main.js → public/build/bundle.js...
LiveReload enabled
(!) `this` has been rewritten to `undefined`
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-this-is-undefined
node_modules/base-64/base64.js
163:   }
164: 
165: }(this));
       ^
```

to conclude: I'm a bit lost :D

thanks in advance